# solve solution curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2-y^2$, given $y(-2)=1$ and $y(0)=2$

i let $y=vx$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$
$$v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=x^2-v^2x^2$$

I'm not sure how to use separation of variables at this stage, or is my apporach wrong?

Comment: LHS is v+xdv/dx.

Comment: Also the function x^2-y^2 is not homogeneous so your substitution of y=vx is wrong.

Comment: i tried again, $\frac{dy}{dx}+y^2=x^2$, $e^{1dx}=e^x=x$ then multiply x back into the equation. $$x\frac{dy}{dx}+xy^2=x^3$$. it does not seem right

Comment: @JeanLow Its not an LDE.

Comment: @MaxPayne so how can i approach this que?